# Resistance to Price rise

Tags: stock-analysis

The following is the chart for **UBER**. You can see in the chart that from **December 16th to 19th**, the stock drops and then try to rise above **30** but can't. The **NASDAQ** index is rising, but **UBER** does not.

What would be the technical reason why the price is not rising above 30 significantly? I'm not looking for a specific answer to the **UBER** stock, but a general reason for any stock which is facing a resistance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The really short answer is that there was not  enough buying volume  to enable a penetration of the $30 level.

After a month long decline, UBER broke below $31 in late Sep, bounced a few times and retested the $29-$31 area until it dropped to $26  in early November where it has struggled since.

If you buy into the premise that there's a significant effect to support & resistance then  support becomes resistance and resistance becomes support.  Here's a generic example of the former (and what appears to be happening to UBER):

[image]

A good way to determine support & resistance is to use a Point & Figure chart.  It eliminates the noise.  You can also see it with trend lines.

Support & Resistance is an inexact science.  You can also debate whether it's a science at all :->)

Answer (score 2):

There's not a "general" reason but two strong possibilities come to mind:

- There are very few buyers that are willing to pay more than $30
- There are a lot of sellers that are willing to sell at $30.

So in general, I guess, it's either a lack of demand (buyers) above that price or an abundance of supply (sellers) at that price.

Of course, *why* there's resistance at that level is anybody's guess.